# What does しまったり mean?

Tags: grammar, meaning

In this line from a song,

> 大人【おとな】になるにつれ 遠【とお】ざかってしまったり

I'm tempted to say it translates to

> As you grow older, you're growing apart (from me)

but I'm not entirely sure how to interpret しまったり. It doesn't seem to be a form of 〜たり, but I can't find much explanation of 〜り either. Could someone help me understand the grammar here?

Edit: As I research more and more, I'm questioning more and more my parsing of the sentence. So if I have it completely wrong, please correct me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To me, this looks like morphological building blocks being strung together.

So you have the main verb in て-form: [遠]{とお}ざか**って**

Then this is followed by しまう, a construction which indicates that the action was accidental (or finished completely). So 食べて**しまいました** means either "I accidentally ate it" or "I ate it all".

In the example you gave, the しまう is in たり form (create with the rule: short past form + り) which is used to mean "things like X"- in this case, "you're doing things like (totally/accidentally) growing apart from me", etc.

Comment: This is correct, except that てしまう in this case doesn't mean "accidentally" or "completely"; it means "unfortunately," or "to my dismay," which is probably the most common use of that construction.