# What does "the library is cool" have to do with summer?

Tags: translation, meaning

In this line from a song about summer things (I previously asked about the same song [here](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/52926/what-does-%E3%81%97%E3%81%BE%E3%81%A3%E3%81%9F%E3%82%8A-mean)...), I'm just slightly confused.

> 図書館涼しくて 7時でも明くて 
>     *toshokan suzushikute shichiji de mo akarukute*

When translating literally, I'd say it means

> The library is cool, it's bright even at 7 o'clock

But I'm kind of missing how this piece fits into the theme of summer. With the artist describing the library as "cool/refreshing", does he possibly mean that it's one of the only places around with A/C? It would make sense if it's a rural area, but I was wondering if this maybe has some sort of cultural connotation to it?

Comment: I think most stores and public buildings are cool with air conditioner in summer. I guess it is a personal experience and doesn't have some sort of cultural connotation.

Comment: I can live with that. Kinda odd though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on how old the lyrics writer was and what environment they belonged. It depends on the financial state of them. I think they are not so rich.

Furthermore, it depends on where they lived.

If they were students and had to spend the whole day at home during the summer vacation, it might be expensive to use the A/C whole day long. Their parents would not allow it, although it is not likely these days. Going outside to a beach or a mountain seems fun but very hot. If they have to do their homework, a library might be a perfect place. If they only have to kill time, a library might still be a perfect place. They can kill time all day long and it is completely free. No money is needed. If they go to a department store, they have to keep walking and would be tired. If they go to a family restaurant or McDonald's, they have to pay some money and they can't stay there more than a couple of hours. Young people would never think, but the elderly people would prevent to use the A/C in order to save money, and they sometimes even suffer from heat strokes these days. For this reason, I'd like to know how old the writer is or how old the parents of the writer are.

I don't know whether this is a particular Japanese culture or not, but a Japanese can think of the merit of a library with no difficulty.

Furthermore, in the west of Japan, seven o'clock in the evening in the summer is still light outside. Therefore, the location might be the east or the middle of Japan.

Hope this helps!

Comment: That is a logical approach to it. I think I have a better grasp of the lyric now, I appreciate it